# Angular does not encapsulate css when using View encapsulation

Tags: css, angular, angular2viewencapsulation

I Have two menus in my app.

Both of them are using primeng [Panel Menu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu)

I have changed their css.

The problem is now after adding the `second-menu` to my app, `left-menu`'s style has changed.

I tried to use `View encapsulation` on both of them, the `left-menu` style still not encapsulated

Here's the **first menu** header

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-menu',
  templateUrl: './left-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-menu.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated

})
```

**Second menu**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-second-menu',
  templateUrl: './second-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second-menu.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
```

In my CSS I use `ng-deep` and `:host`

here's an example

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-default:hover {
  background-color: #555555;

}
```

Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue-tm8c63?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

I won't add all the CSS because it's the same on both styles

Comment: could you make a stackblitz ? (you can use this one as start : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-view-encapsulation)

Comment: I have added a demo

Answer (score 0):

Using only `::ng-deep` will affect all the classes in the project even if not children of the component where the css is declared. ([here is a simple stackblitz reproduting this behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-view-encapsulation))

If you want to affect only child elements of the component but not the elements on the same level, you should use `:host` with the `::ng-deep`.

[Here is a fork of your stackblitz with a fix suggestion.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49771722)